# I can't change the active page name on the navigation bar

Tags: javascript, html, css

I made a navigation bar, but when I go to mobile version, and I go on another page, the name in the navigation bar doesn't change. See the image below so that you can understand me.

[image: navbar]

**Working snippet:**

```js
function myFunction() {
  var x = document.getElementById("myTopnav");
  if (x.className === "topnav") {
    x.className += " responsive";
  } else {
    x.className = "topnav";
  }
}
```

```css
ul.topnav {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #666;
  box-shadow: 3px 5px 30px black;
  border-radius: 5px;
}

ul.topnav li {
  float: left;
  display: inline;
}

ul.topnav li a {
  display: inline-block;
  color: #f2f2f2;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  transition: 0.3s;
  font-size: 17px;
}

.topnav a:link,
.topnav a:visited {
  padding: 10px 25px;
  height: 20px;
}

ul.topnav li a:hover {
  background-color: #555;
}

ul.topnav li.icon {
  display: none;
}

.active {
  background-color: #E91A15;
}


@media screen and (max-width:770px) {
  ul.topnav li:not(:first-child) {display: none;}
  ul.topnav li.icon {
    float: right;
    display: inline-block;
  }
}

@media screen and (max-width:770px) {
  ul.topnav.responsive {position: relative;}
  ul.topnav.responsive li.icon {
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
  }
  ul.topnav.responsive li {
    float: none;
    display: inline;
  }
  ul.topnav.responsive li a {
    display: block;
    text-align: left;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<header class="mainHeader">
  <nav>
    <ul class="topnav" id="myTopnav">
      <li><a class="active" href="home.html">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="OverOns.html">Over Ons</a></li>
      <li><a href="Contact.html">Contact</a></li>
      <li><a href="Offerte.html">Offerte</a></li>
      <!--<li><a href="Jobs.html">Jobs</a></li>-->
      <li><a href="Fotos.html">Fotos</a></li>
      <li class="icon">
        <a href="javascript:void(0);" style="font-size:15px;" onclick="myFunction()">☰</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</header>
```

Thank you !

Comment: Where is your logic to change the active menu item? Also, why include jQuery and not use it?

Comment: I use the program "Brackets" and it works on there because I put the script in my html under the navigation bar.